# GCMLE Model runtime version

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Is there a way to check the runtime version of a GCMLE prediction service model? From the UI, I can see the model and model location, but I can't remember if the model was pushed with 1.6, 1.7 or 1.8 and would like to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`gcloud ml-engine models describe` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/models/describe) from the `gcloud` CLI tool in order to obtain more details about the model and its current default version.

Running this command, will return something like:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine models describe census
defaultVersion:
  createTime: '2018-06-05T11:54:35Z'
  deploymentUri: gs://GCS/model/location
  framework: TENSORFLOW
  isDefault: true
  name: projects/PROJECT_ID/models/MODEL_NAME/versions/VERSION_NAME
  pythonVersion: '2.7'
  runtimeVersion: '1.7'    <---- This is what you are interested in
  state: READY
name: projects/PROJECT_ID/models/MODEL_NAME
regions:
- us-central1
```

Otherwise, you can find more details about specific ML Engine model versions with the [`gcloud ml-engine versions describe` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/versions/describe) too.

Comment: Perfect! One step further for my exact use case if you have different versions the command would be `gcloud ml-engine versions describe <VERSION> --model <MODEL>